# Different problems with beamer

Tags: beamer, titles, frame-title

I am using `beamer` for a presentation and I encountered different problems:

1. In the title page, the background image I added does not cover the whole frame: the header is still white.
2. The title/subtitle background and my image background there is a whitespace, caused by the gray to white gradient of the title/subtitle background.
3. The bibliography is badly formatted.

This is a MVW that reproduces my problems:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}                                          
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}


\author[]{Author name here}
\title{\huge Cool title here\\ \large Ugly withe space on top of this frame}
\date{Date here}
\institute[]{Badass institution}

\begin{document}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\makebox[\paperheight][c]{\tikz\node[opacity=0.5]{\includegraphics[height=1\paperheight]{EPFL_LOG_col.pdf}};}}}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\tikz\node[opacity=0.05]{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{EPFL_LOG_mut_small.pdf}};}}

\section*{Introduction}
\subsection*{}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    \framesubtitle{}

    Note the white space caused by the gradient from the title background to white. Citation: \citet{Citation}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}

    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]
[image]
[image]

**It is possible to fix these problems? If yes, how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't make it overly complicated with all these nested boxes - as you are already using `tikz`, you can just place the image in the centre of the page and specify its width and height:

   ```
   \usebackgroundtemplate{%
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \node[at=(current page.center),opacity=0.5] {
           \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}
       };
       \end{tikzpicture}
   }
   ```
2. To remove the shadow below the frametitle:

   ```
   \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]
   ```
3. Well, that's the fault of the style you are using, take another one.

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]


\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Knu86,
        author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
        year = {1986},
        title = {The \TeX book},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,hyperref,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\author[]{Author name here}
\title{\huge Cool title here\\ \large Ugly withe space on top of this frame}
\date{Date here}
\institute[]{Badass institution}

\begin{document}

    \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

    \usebackgroundtemplate{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[at=(current page.center),opacity=0.5] {
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    {
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
        \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
        \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
        \begin{frame}
            \maketitle
        \end{frame}
    }

    \usebackgroundtemplate{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[at=(current page.center),opacity=0.5] {
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \section*{Introduction}
    \subsection*{}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Introduction}
        \framesubtitle{}

        Note the white space caused by the gradient from the title background to white. Citation: \citet{Citation}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]